# How to increase kernel loglevel in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a machine that's going down often and I would like to increase the loglevel of the kernel on it to capture what may be going on.

When I change `/etc/default/grub` to include `loglevel=7` in the kernel parameters, it appears to boot with that in the command line, but I see no additional kernel messages in the logs or dmesg.

Is there some trick that Ubuntu needs to get this done?

Comment: did you run "sudo update-grub"  ? reboot after that

Comment: Yes. This was not overlooked.